# some test cases aren't running - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

the problem is an image so I'll try to abbreviate and write it out:

there are 2 football teams. For every match of team B compute the total number of matches that team A has scored less than or equal to team B in that match. For example:

```
team A : [2,3,4]
team B : [3,5]

the output will be : [2,3]
```

my solution so far:

```
function counts(teamA, teamB) {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < teamB.length; i++){
        let newArr = teamA.filter(some => some <= teamB[i])
        arr.push(newArr.length)
            }
    return arr
}
```

Only some test cases pass (can't see what isn't passing). Any thoughts as to what I'm missing here?

edit: Here is another test case as an example:

[image]

Comment: Please define the problem including the inputs and expected outputs and any constraints precisely and unambiguously.

Comment: this is unclear, how `[2,3]` will be computed in human logic ?

Comment: @MoB.sorry I added another test case to show how the question works.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is what you are looking for...

```js
const count = (teamA, teamB) => teamB.map(B => teamA.filter(A => A<=B).length );

console.log(JSON.stringify( count([2,3,4], [3,5])) )    // [ 2,3 ]
console.log(JSON.stringify( count([1,4,2,4], [3,5])) )  // [ 2,4 ]
```

Comment: While that returns the same result for the given input, it is most likely not what OP is asking about. Have a look at their code. Their logic is completely different.

Comment: @str that's why I ask him if this answer is what he is looking for or not! this answer is to be understood as a question with an example . And there is no logic in his code, I also asked him for more explanation in a comment ...

Comment: @MisterJojo I posted an example test cases the question provided to be clearer. Sorry for being vague I'm just trying to communicate the info that was given to me

Comment: @MisterJojo still no luck, but thank you for the help!

Comment: @st123  How that ? this is exactly the logic you show